# Gem thumbs_up shorthand syntax issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

In `thumbs_up` [documentation](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up) there is **Shorthand Syntax** section.

```
...
voter.vote(voteable, vote)
...
```

What's a `vote` that is coming as a second parameter there? How could I define it or where from I could get it?

Comment: [documentation](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up#shorthand-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

vote is a option hash.

`voter.vote(voteable, direction: :down)` would be a downvote.

&

`voter.vote(voteable, direction: :up)` would be a upvote. `

**EDIT:**

The documentation seems to have some differences with the code :P

Comment: Thank you. Well, now it makes a sense.

Comment: Are you sure it's a boolean? It doesn't seem so in the code https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up/blob/master/lib/acts_as_voter.rb#L85-L95

Comment: Good catch there, updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the documentation for `vote` was incorrect and I've submitted a PR to fix this https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up/pull/104

`vote` takes a second argument which is a hash of options. The `direction` key of the hash is a required key which needs to have a value of `:up` or `:down`.

Comment: Are you sure it's a boolean? It doesn't seem so in the code https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up/blob/master/lib/acts_as_voter.rb#L85-L95

Comment: @SimoneCarletti then it seems like a documentation error and due for a PR ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can find it [in the source code](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up/blob/2c626024707c3a127d9f652c3cfd1febeff758e2/lib/acts_as_voter.rb#L85-L95). It's a `Hash` of options.

This method seems to be the base utility function for the various vote helpers. You should probably use `vote_for`.